# Adding く to な-adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I was playing Fire Emblem If (暗夜) yesterday and came across a construction I did not know beforehand, な-adjectives apparently turned into adverbs using く.

> お前｛まえ｝のことは、父上｛ちちうえ｝に上手｛じょうず｝く言っておこう

I am not sure I understand the function of `上手く` here. My rough translation is:

> Let's prepare your father by telling him about what you did well.

But I am not sure at all about how 上手 fits into this sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one's weird because it's not actually じょうず like you'd think; it's うまい, which is an i-adjective and can be conjugated like you see there.

Now, translation is not exactly one of my stronger suits, but I was able to find a dictionary entry for this on Jisho: http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8A%E6%89%8B%E3%81%8F

Comment: I think 上手い（うまい） is not a "textbook" reading, but it appears very often.

Comment: Translation perhaps: "Let's put in a good word about you to dad."